# Classroom management software; storing data?

Tags: database, content-management-system

So I am working on a mini-project for the summer to keep my coding skills sharp.  I will be using the Qt4 and C++ to make a classroom management system for college professors.  I just came up with the idea like 10 minutes ago so I don't have much.

One question I have is what is the best way to store student/class/assignment information so that the software could still be portable and used my different schools.

My first guess would be a MySQL database.  I need a gurus opinion on this one though.

Comment: If you've only been thinking about the project for ten minutes then the choice of database (even the choice between server and desktop) is premature. I suggest that you work out the use case design first. (We produce an SDK designed for just this kind of thing. If you're interested, we'd love to have you involved in beta testing. I won't post details until you ask, because it's hardly appropriate to plug products here, but please do reply to this comment if you're interested.)

Comment: The Moodle Course Management System is widely used for this sort of thing and it uses MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since different sites have different database preferences you might wish to use a layer such as [ActiveRecord](http://rubyforge.org/projects/activerecord/) or [PDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_Data_Objects) or [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odbc) to abstract out the specific database that your end users want to use. This would allow people to deploy onto [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgresql) or [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysql) or whatever they prefer.

A good choice for single-process server systems could be [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/). It's not suitable for all systems, but if your system is designed to scale to a few dozen users at most, it'll probably work fine. (The amount of work you'd need to put into a server to make SQLite3 scale into the hundreds or thousands might argue for planning for a database server environment instead.)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlite.org/

might be a good option. It is embeddable so you don't need a specific database instance running wherever you deploy it

also, http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx is an option